# Heroku Deploy Error: Cannot get Node App running after Deploy : Cannot find module '/app/web.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have a node.js app using Express and MongoDB (mongoose). It runs perfectly fine locally. I deployed it to heroku seemingly without a problem, but when I try to actually launch the app it crashes. The heroku log says this: Error: Cannot find module '/app/web.js'

I am new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! App will help my Type 1 Diabetic daughter.

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "projectglu",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.3",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.8",
    "connect-mongo": "~0.4.0",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "~0.1.6",
    "ejs": "~0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-bower-install": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-newer": "~0.5.4",
    "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.2.1",
    "grunt-express-server": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
    "connect-livereload": "~0.3.0",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.2",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.10",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.1",
    "karma": "~0.10.9",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.8.1",
    "supertest": "~0.8.2",
    "should": "~2.1.0",
    "grunt-env": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-nodemon": "~0.2.0",
    "open": "~0.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not the information that is needed. Try posting your "app.js" file from the root of your project in your question instead. Or better yet, **just** the lines around where you are calling/loading/requiring '/app/web.js'

Answer (score 3):

More clearly the problem may be when you create the Procfile from Heroku website example you are cutting and pasting "web: node web.js" which basically tells heroku which file is your entry point. You probably have a different entry point like say .. server.js so swap out "web: node web.js" with "web: node server.js" to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variety of issues that can be causing this.

Please check that you have added your 'Procfile'.Use a Procfile, a text file in the root directory of your application, to explicitly declare what command should be executed to start a web dyno. In this case, you simply need to execute the Node script using node.

Here’s an example Procfile:

`web: node web.js`

Another culprit could be a misconfigured environment  variable, `NODE_ENV`. Personally, commanding Heroku to set `NODE_ENV=production` helped me resolved a `Cannot find module` error I experienced. When you do this replace `myapp` with *your* Heroku app name.

`heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production`

If this fails to solve your issue move the packages declared in `devDependencies` over to `dependencies` just to mitigate the `NODE_ENV` issue.